# How is /usr/lib64/libc.so generated?

Tags: linux, glibc, ld

```
[root@xx test]# cat /usr/lib64/libc.so
/* GNU ld script
   Use the shared library, but some functions are only in
   the static library, so try that secondarily.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)
GROUP ( /lib64/libc.so.6 /usr/lib64/libc_nonshared.a  AS_NEEDED ( /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ) )
```

Anyone knows how this kind of stuff is generated?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is generated when glibc is compiled using Make utility.

There is a rule (started by `make install`) in glibc's Makefile, which does just echo needed lines into some temporary file `$@.new`:

```
(echo '/* GNU ld script';\
 echo '   Use the shared library, but some functions are only in';\
 echo '   the static library, so try that secondarily.  */';\
 cat $<; \
 echo 'GROUP ( $(slibdir)/libc.so$(libc.so-version)' \
      '$(libdir)/$(patsubst %,$(libtype.oS),$(libprefix)$(libc-name))'\
      ' AS_NEEDED (' $(slibdir)/$(rtld-installed-name) ') )' \
) > $@.new
```

And then this file is renamed to `libc.so`

```
mv -f $@.new $@
```

Here is a comment from Makefile, which explains a bit:

```
# What we install as libc.so for programs to link against is in fact a
# link script.  It contains references for the various libraries we need.
# The libc.so object is not complete since some functions are only defined
# in libc_nonshared.a.
# We need to use absolute paths since otherwise local copies (if they exist)
# of the files are taken by the linker.
```

I understand this as: `libc.so.6` is not complete and needs something, which can't be stored in shared library. So, glibc developers moved this something to static part of glibc - `libc_nonshared.a`. To force always linking both `libc.so.6` and `libc_nonstared.a`, they created a special linking script which instructs ld linker to use both when it is asked for `-lc` (libc)

What is in the nonshared part? Let's check:

```
$ objdump -t /usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a |grep " F "|grep -v __
00000000 g     F .text  00000058 .hidden atexit
00000000  w    F .text  00000050 .hidden stat
00000000  w    F .text  00000050 .hidden fstat
00000000  w    F .text  00000050 .hidden lstat
00000000 g     F .text  00000050 .hidden stat64
00000000 g     F .text  00000050 .hidden fstat64
00000000 g     F .text  00000050 .hidden lstat64
00000000 g     F .text  00000050 .hidden fstatat
00000000 g     F .text  00000050 .hidden fstatat64
00000000  w    F .text  00000058 .hidden mknod
00000000 g     F .text  00000050 .hidden mknodat
00000000 l     F .text  00000001 nop
```

There are `atexit()`, `*stat*()`, `mknod` functions. Why? Don't know really, but it is a fact of glibc.

Here is some long explaination http://giraffe-data.com/~bryanh/giraffehome/d/note/proglib and I cite beginning of it:

```
The stat() family of functions and mknod() are special.  Their
interfaces are tied so tightly to the underlying operating system that
they change occasionally.
```

Comment: So each time glibc is updated,it'll point to the latest version of implementation. What about those binaries that depend on the old version? How to ensure those binaries still work with the new glibc?

Comment: @compile-fan, compiled binary have a glibc version hardcoded in it. The working with different ABI versions of *stat and mknod is task for kernel, so if you try to use a program from redhat 5 (not a rhel but a linux from 199x), kernel will emulate old abi as it is mostly backward compatible. Glibc version for this program will be from redhat 5 (e.g. glibc-2.0 or even earlier; file libc.so.5), not the libc.so.6

Comment: if program was linked with older version of libc.so.6, and uses some library interface which is obsoleted or changed in newer glibc, then library must provide several versions of the function to be backward compatible. You can see versioned versions of functions with `objdump  -T /bin/echo|grep GLIBC`

Comment: @osgx , I know that normal .so files uses the `ldconfig` to create the necessary links and cache to the most recent shared libraries(that is by using `ln -s`), why is `glibc` using a different way(by using a script file `/usr/lib64/libc.so`) ?

Comment: compile-fan, glibc is very different, it is a basic library, which solves internally a lot of problems. This is a design decision.

Comment: @osgx,what's the relationship between glibc and linux kernel?Is it included in the linux kernel source code?

Comment: glibc interacts with kernel interfaces. Both kernel interfaces and glibc interfaces changes over time. Task of glibc is to hide all interface changes from application and to provide backward compatibility. Not, glibc is not included in kernel source, but glibc uses some linux kernel headers.

Answer (score -1):

On managed systems you may need to install glibc-devel and/or glibc-devel.i686.